# Unable to boot from new SSD after installing from USB

Tags: boot, ssd

I'm using a new SSD with nothing on it. It's installed via USB drive, and boots from USB as well. While in Ubuntu I can see the SSD and other devices. When I install from the desktop (have tried from the boot screen as well), system restarts. It takes me to the boot screen, select boot from first hard disk, nothing, goes right back to boot screen.  When I take the USB out, it hangs on "Verifing DMI."  If I boot onto the USB I can see the correct files located in the SSD.

I have a basic knowledge of computers. Give me any thing you think would help.

No other OS's are loaded.

```
Gigabyte ga-k8n-sli
1GB RAM
AMD Athlon 64 x2 dual core 3800+
OCZ SSD Agility 3 120GB
```

Answer (score 3):

OK - apparently, all one has to do is install grub on the new SSD drive:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
```

Also, if you want to get rid of the old OS in the grub menu, probably the easiest way is to copy over the old `/boot/` folder to say `/backup_boot/`, and then run `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 0):

this is just a thing just from the top of my head.
when i had build a pc the first time i had the same thing.
in the BIOS i needed to change the boot order of the hard drives.

Comment: You may want to elaborate little more explaining the solution

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

Computer stops at verifying dmi pool data.

### Cause

This issue can be caused by any of the below reasons.

```
Corrupt boot files on the computer.
Settings for hard drive are not correct.
Floppy diskette or CD in computer causing issue.
Boot devices not set properly.
BIOS corrupt or misc. setting not set properly.
Connections loose or disconnected.
Bad hard drive or other bad hardware.
```

### Solutions

- Corrupt boot files on the computer

If the computer has no bootable files on the drive, you will need to boot from a DVD or USB. Ensure that Linux has been properly installed first or your boot manager is not corrupt.

- Settings for hard drive are not correct

The computer freezing at "Verifying dmi pool data..." may be caused when the hard drive settings within CMOS are not set properly. Enter CMOS setup and verify that the hard drive settings are set properly and that it is set to Auto Detect.

- Floppy diskette or CD in computer causing issue

Verify no floppy diskette or CD is in the computer. In some cases the computer may be trying to boot from either of these drives causing issues with the boot sequence.

- Boot devices not set properly

The computer stopping at " verifying dmi pool data..." can be caused when the boot devices on your computer are not set properly in CMOS. First, verify that no CD or diskette is in your computer. If a CD or diskette is in the computer remove this first to determine if it was attempting to boot from it.

If No CD or diskette is in the computer and your computer still halts at the DMI message enter CMOS setup and verify that the boot options are set properly. We commonly recommend that the floppy be set the first boot device, hard drive as the second boot device and the CD-ROM as the third boot device.

- BIOS corrupt or misc. setting not set properly

If none of the above recommendations have resolved your issue, reset the BIOS or CMOS settings to the factory or default settings.

- Connections loose or disconnected

If the computer has been recently moved or new hardware has been installed in the computer it is possible that a connection may be loose or even disconnected. Verify that the hard drive, floppy and CD-ROM cables are properly connected.

- Bad hard drive or other bad hardware

If you computer continues to freeze at the DMI message after attempting all of the above recommendations it is possible that the computer may be freezing because of a bad hard drive or other bad hardware in the computer.

Before replacing any hardware we first recommend you erase everything on the hard drive and start over.

If you're unable to get to the point of re-installing the operating system it's likely your computer has a hardware issue and it's suggested that the hard drive be replaced. If that doesn't resolve the issue then have the motherboard replaced.

Source [www.computerhope.com](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000474.htm)